# Getting DHCP Scope Options using Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, dhcp, windows-server-2003-r2

I need to get the DHCP scope option values using Powershell 2.0 on Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2.
I don't have access to the Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue commandlet since that's only available on Windows Server 2012 R2.

How can I get the DHCP scope option values without using the Get-Dhcp commandlets?

Answer (score 0):

You may do this [via WMI](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66210404-e80c-4077-987f-84f8fc92eac8/monitor-dhcp-server-statistics-via-wmi?forum=winserverpowershell) or use `net.exe` and then parse the text in PowerShell where needed